# Django Edit Listing Form Not Updating

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a listing system on my website and am currently creating a page which allows the user to edit their listing, I've got most of it working however I am stuck on saving their updated form. Currently if they save the edited form rather than updating the model it creates a whole new listing entry and still leaves the old one there. If anyone could please look at my code that would be great.

View -

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='login')
def editlisting(request, pk):

    post = JobListing.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if str(request.user) != str(post.user):
        return redirect("index")

    if request.method == "POST":
        print("test")
        form = JobListingForm(request.POST, instance=post)

        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = request.user
            profile.save()
            return redirect('index')

    else:
        print("else")
        form = JobListingForm(instance=post)

    context = {
        "form": form
    }

    return render(request, "editlisting.html", context)
```

Model -

```
class JobListing(models.Model):

    region_choice = (
        ('1', 'Auckland'),
        ('2', 'Wellington'),
        ('3', 'Christchurch')
    )
    industry_choice = (
        ('1', 'Accounting'),
        ('2', 'Agriculture, fishing & forestry'),
        ('3', 'Automotive'),
        ('4', 'Banking, finance & insurance'),
        ('5', 'Construction & Architecture'),
        ('6', 'Customer service'),
    )
    employment_type_choice = (
        ('1', 'Full Time'),
        ('2', 'Part Time'),
        ('3', 'One-off'),
        ('4', 'Other')
    )

    user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pay_rate = models.FloatField()
    employment_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=employment_type_choice)
    job_description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    business_address_region = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=region_choice)
    business_address_suburb = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    business_industry = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=industry_choice)
    contact_method = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active_listing = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Job Listing'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.business_name
```

Piece of code from my registration app which could be affecting it?

```
def signup(self, request, user):
    SignUpProfile.objects.create(
        user=user,
        account_type=self.cleaned_data['account_type'],
        contact_number=self.cleaned_data['contact_number']
    )
```

Form -

```
class JobListingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = JobListing
        fields = ['job_title', 'business_name', 'pay_rate', 'employment_type', 'job_description', 'business_address_region',
            'business_address_suburb', 'business_industry', 'contact_method']
        widgets = {
            'job_title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'required': 'true', 'placeholder': 'Job Title'}),
            'business_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'required': 'true', 'placeholder': 'Name of Business'}),
            'pay_rate': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'required': 'true', 'placeholder': 'Hourly Rate or One Off Amount'}),
            'employment_type': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'required': 'true'}),
            'job_description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-textarea', 'required': 'true',
                'placeholder': 'Tell us additional information about your job listing e.g. Times, Business Info, Number of positions etc. (2000 Character Limit)'}),
            'business_address_region': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'required': 'true'}),
            'business_address_suburb': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'required': 'true', 'placeholder': 'Business Suburb'}),
            'business_industry': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'required': 'true'}),
            'contact_method': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'required': 'true', 'placeholder': 'Email or Contact Number'}),
        }
```

Comment: Why do you want to set `profile.user = request.user` since it will already present while inserting new record

Comment: I was meaning to remove that, but even with it removed it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Since you've removed that, does it still create a new entry if you let the `form.save()` commit the changes? (and have you overridden any save methods)

Comment: Yes, it still creates the new entry. The only save method which could possibly be affecting it is what I have written as is required by allauth the registration app I am using. Since I extended the model I was required to put a signup function into the signup form. I will add it to my post.

Comment: I don't think that `signup` method will have anything to do with the issue, you could test this by setting a breakpoint in that method and seeing if it is hit. I can't see any issues with the code you have provided..

Comment: If you're not using an IDE with a debugger (find one :D) you can change your signup method to use `get_or_create` instead of `create` to see if that fixes the issue

Comment: Please post the code for JobListingForm.

Comment: I have added the form code